# How to control bit rate/bandwidth in netperf? Equivalent to -b option in iperf?

Tags: bandwidth, throughput, iperf

I am trying to test the throughput of my network using netperf utility and want to send data at different bit rates. 
There is -b option in iperf to control this but I am looking for same option in netperf.

Answer (score 0):

If you

```sh
./configure netperf
```

with `--enable-intervals` or `--enable-spin` and then build the `netperf` binary, two additional global command-line options will be enabled:

```
-w <time>  burst interval - time between bursts of sends etc
-b <count> burst count - number of sends, etc to perform in an interval
```

with that, you can control the rate at which `netperf` sends data.